# Eclipse won't reckognize and validate JSP tag dir attributes

Tags: eclipse, jsp, taglib

I'm currently using Spring Source Tools 2.9.1 - but I had the same issue with standard Eclipse J2EE distribution.

I'm writing java web application with jsp views.

To better reuse code I have created some tags - `*.tag` files in `WEB-INF\tags` folder

Example of `enum.tag` file:

```
<jsp:root version="2.0" 
    xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" 
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
    xmlns:tags="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags"
    xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <jsp:directive.tag pageEncoding="UTF-8" />

    <jsp:directive.attribute name="value" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" type="Object" />
    <jsp:directive.attribute name="cssClass" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" />

    <span class="enum ${value.cssClass} ${cssClass}"> 
        <span class="message"> 
            <spring:message code="${value.name}" />
        </span>
    </span>

</jsp:root>
```

If I use this tag in my jsp the tag is reckognized by validator, but the tag attributes are not.

so I get warning for this line of jsp

```
<tags:enum value="${t.state}" />
```

warning:

```
Undefined attribute name "value"
```

tag nemaspace is initialized with:

```
xmlns:tags="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags
```

How to setup eclipse to properly validate tagdir's tags?

Comment: Same behavior occurs with Eclipse Indigo SR2 and JBoss Tools. If the tags are directly in WEB-INF/tags, attributes are recognized, but if they are in a JAR declared with <tag-file> in a TLD, they are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use XML version of jsps (and tags) - all teh fiels are valid XML documents, it uses syntax like

```
<jsp:directive.tag pageEncoding="UTF-8" body-content="scriptless" />

<jsp:directive.attribute name="caption" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" />
<jsp:directive.attribute name="labelInfix" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" />
```

I now realized and checked that I need to use tagx extension (alongside jspx). With this change Eclispe validation works well.

Comment: It only works with tagx and jspx? I'll try when I have time (lots of refactoring going on here), but I really prefer tag and jsp (the xml syntax is a little too verbose).

Comment: I'm using xml version for both, I was using jspx and tag extesions, now I tested renaming one tag to tagx and it helped - So I can confirm that this is working

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as of the time of this writing, using Eclipse Luna, Eclipse's JSP tag validation for custom tags in JARs (called 'packaged tag files' by Oracle) is still horrible. I have two Java projects, one which contains the JAR which has my .tags and TLD (the TLD has  elements). I managed to get the JSP tag validation e.g. `<t:customTag />` working but Eclipse still marks all attributes in yellow as "undefined attribute name".

I was able to get the tag validation working in my dependent project by:

1. Adding the tag project to Build path->Projects->"Required projects
   on the build path"
2. In my JAR/tag project itself, under Java build path->Order and
   export, I marked the JAR file itself as exported.